# Foreign Key Referencing Same Table

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, key

I've searched well and can't find an answer explaining the problem well.  Here is a simplified example of my issue.  Let's say I have a table `test` with two fields `first` and `second`.  I make `first` the primary key and want `second` to reference `first` and cascade on update.  This will allow me to make a list of rows, knowing which row comes after any given row, unless the 'head'.

Creating the table works fine, however when I try to add a row it complains that the foreign key constraint with cascading update failed.  This makes sense, as I left `second` as null.  Therefore, I thought I could insert two rows and then add the foreign key:

1. `first: a     second: b`
2. `first: b     second: a`

This was successful.  I then tried updating row 1 to have a `first` value of `c`.  However, this didn't work, stating the foreign key failed.  Why?  Shouldn't it just become the following?

1. `first: c     second: b`
2. `first: b     second: c`

My only hunch is the existence of circular updates with the update to row 1 cascading to row 2, cascading back to row 1, but this shouldn't happen!  There is nothing referencing `second`, so the update should just cascade to row 2 and stop.  Please help, this is driving me crazy.

Edit: As requested, here's my `show create table test`.

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
 `first` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
 `second` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`first`),
KEY `fk` (`second`),
CONSTRAINT `fk` FOREIGN KEY (`second`) REFERENCES `test` (`first`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is in the structure of columns:

- primary key can't be null
- and your referencing column has allowed null value, (not allowed when referenced column is not null)

So make sure you have both columns with same data type, same charset, not null both.

**Update**: problem is that foreign key and referencing key is in the same table, I've tested with different table and it worked.

Comment: The primary key is not null, since it's going to be c for row one and b for row two.  Also, the referencing column will not have a null value either.  It will be b for row one and c for row two.

Comment: it will not have null value but ? please can you paste `show create table test` to see the structure. thanks

Comment: Thanks, I've tried different solutions but non worked, problem is that it's referencing in the same table, with different tables it works